# How to add data stored in one variable to another data field inside data return in Nuxt?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, fullcalendar, nuxt.js, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to add Full Calendar to my Nuxt project. Here is my code.

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <!-- {{calendarOptions}} -->
        <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" />
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
    import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
    import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
    import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
    
    export default {
      components: {
        FullCalendar, // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
      },
      data() {
        return {
          allevents: [{ title: 'Event 2', start: '2021-01-04', end: '2021-01-07' },
          { title: 'Event 3', start: '2021-01-05', end: '2021-01-09' }],

          calendarOptions: {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            nowIndicator: true,
          
            events: [
              { title: 'Event 1', start: '2021-01-01', end: '2021-01-03' },            
            ],               
          },
        }
      },
    }
    </script>
```

I want to add data in **allevents** **array** to **events array** inside **calenderOptions object**.
Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method to push data from your `allevents` array to the `calendarOptions.events` array.

```
methods: {
  doTheThing() {
    this.allevents.forEach(event => {
       this.calendarOptions.events.push(event)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answering. I just found the solution on my own. The only difference is I did the above thing inside mounted(). So as the page loads up, I can get the data as I want.